# using template literals with classlist attribute

Tags: javascript, methods, attributes, template-literals

javascript newbie here.
I'm trying to implement template literals to change the second part of a variable name while calling the toggle method with the classlist attribute. Here's what I have:

`bigBoxRight.classList.toggle("turnOff");`

and this is what i'm trying to accomplish:

`` bigBox`${player}`.classList.toggle("turnOff"); ``

Player can be both "Right" or "Left" and it's a string.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to save another variable that will get the element you need based on your decision
and then get the classlist for it

For example

```
const bigBoxRight = docemnt.querySelector...
const bigBoxLeft = docemnt.querySelector...

const elemRef = true* ? bigBoxRight : bigBoxLeft 

elemRef.classList.toggle("turnOff");

*-  Your logic for when you need the right or the left  bigbox element
```

Tim's solution might be cleaner if you know when you need the right element or the left

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to dynamically create variable names, you should get the element you are trying to toggle the class on first.

Assuming bigBoxRight or bigBoxLeft is the id of the element, you can use your template literals to get the element first:

```
var elem = document.querySelector(`#bigBox${player}`)
```

Then you can do:

```
elem.classList.toggle("turnOff");
```

Comment: yes but that's what i was trying to avoid